# How can one add text files in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mmap, gridfs

I have certain requirement to insert a text file in mongodb, retrieve it back and then check that whether files are same. I am hoping to do it without GridFS as the files i want to use is lesser than 16MB, so can you guys plz suggest me ways to do it, considering that set up of mongodb is very basic one.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to do this via some server side language (PHP, Python etc.)?

Comment: no simple mongo shell commands would do

Comment: You can find all the information you need here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS

Comment: @xbonez - thanks for the help! this link explains just about gridfs, i want to do it without gridfs.

Comment: Without gridfs you can just store it in the document as as `$bin` format, however I am not completely sure the JS terminal has IO capabilities since that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/File_object is the closest thing but it is no longer used and is not standard. So I think you would have to use a server-side language to read it in

Comment: @manida: Oh sorry, I misread your question that you were looking to use GridFS

Comment: xbonez - not a problem
Sammaye - so u saying that with mongo shell only, even if save the file with bin data type, I ll not be able to read the file back for comparison. In that case using gridfs becomes essential. So one more question, if I use gridfs will the stored file still remain mmap'ed?

Comment: Oh you can you read back from the database it is just that the JavaScript engine MongoDB uses has no way to read from filesystem I believe, but if you mean compare to file system then yea you can't. Yes they will remain memory mapped.

Comment: thnx!!! it really helped

Comment: http://bsonspec.org/#/specification BinData

Answer (score 2):

A text file that is less than 16 MB can be stored as a simple key-value pair in a plain document. No need for GridFS and no need for Binary or JSON objects. If in doubt, try it. It works. Read the contents of the file into a variable and store it against a key such as, I don't know, 'data'. Retrieve the object and write the value of the 'data' key to whatever you like. Line breaks are all preserved so no need to do anything within the file. Really simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert JSON objects or binary files (both stored as BSON objects) to mongodb.

If you want to insert content of a text file, than you can insert it as a JSON object.

But if you want to insert a text file or binary file, you have to use GridFS.

There is no way to insert a file to mongodb without GridFS unless you split the file into chunks and store as JSON object which is what GridFS already doing.