# storing full text from txt file into mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

I have created a python script that automates a workflow converting PDF to txt files. I want to be able to store and query these files in MongoDB. Do I need to turn the .txt file into JSON/BSON? Should I be using a program like PyMongo?

I am just not sure what the steps of such a project would be let alone the tools that would help with this.

I've looked at this post: [How can one add text files in Mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081660/how-can-one-add-text-files-in-mongodb), which makes me think I need to convert the file to a JSON file, and possibly integrate GridFS?

Comment: If they're small files, you won't need GridFS. If they're large (>10MB), you'd want to use GridFS more than likely.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to JSON/BSON encode it if you're using a driver. If you're using the MongoDB shell, you'd need to worry about it when you pasted the contents.

You'd likely want to use the [Python MongoDB driver](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/index.html):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.test_database  # use a database called "test_database"
collection = db.files   # and inside that DB, a collection called "files"

f = open('test_file_name.txt')  # open a file
text = f.read()    # read the entire contents, should be UTF-8 text

# build a document to be inserted
text_file_doc = {"file_name": "test_file_name.txt", "contents" : text }
# insert the contents into the "file" collection
collection.insert(text_file_doc)
```

*(Untested code)*

If you made sure that the file names are unique, you could set the `_id` property of the document and retrieve it like:

```
text_file_doc = collection.find_one({"_id": "test_file_name.txt"})
```

Or, you could ensure the `file_name` property as shown above is indexed and do:

```
text_file_doc = collection.find_one({"file_name": "test_file_name.txt"})
```

Your other option is to use GridFS, although it's often not recommended for small files.

There's a starter [here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/gridfs.html) for Python and GridFS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must convert your file to JSON. There is a trivial way to do that: use something like `{"text": "your text"}`. It's easy to extend / update such records later.

Of course you'd need to escape the `"` occurences in your text. I suppose that you use a JSON library and/or MongoDB library of your favorite language to do all the formatting.

Comment: Any recommendations on how to convert to JSON? I've seen posts referring to gelatin but I'm not sure if that is the best tool.

Comment: You shouldn't need to convert the text file to json.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I can store the whole text file as a single field into MongoDb using GridFS?