# how to transfer .txt to MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb

I would like to ask how to use python to convert a .txt file into MongoDB.

The .txt file is huge (ca. 800M) but has a simple data structure:

```
title1...TAB...text1text1text1text1text1text1\n
title2...TAB...text2text2text2text2text2text2\n
title3...TAB...text3text3text3text3text3text3\n
```

The `...TAB...` means there is a tab key, or a big space. (Sorry I don't know exactly how to describe it.)

The desired MongoDB format should be look like:

```
{ 
“title”: title1,
“description”: text1text1text1text1text1text1\n,
“extra”: EMPTY
}
... and so on.
```

I tried with the code from [storing full text from txt file into mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307552/storing-full-text-from-txt-file-into-mongodb)

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.test_database  # use a database called "test_database"
collection = db.files   # and inside that DB, a collection called "files"

f = open('F:\\ttt.txt')  # open a file
text = f.read()    # read the entire contents, should be UTF-8 text

# build a document to be inserted
text_file_doc = {"file_name": "F:\\ttt.txt", "contents" : text }
# insert the contents into the "file" collection
collection.insert(text_file_doc)
```

To be honest, as a newbie I don't quite understand what the code means. So it is not surprise that the code above doesn't work for my purpose.

Could anybody please help me out of this problem? Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It boils down to how your input file is formatted.
If it consistently follows the format you outlined, i.e. there's no tabs/whitespace characters in the title portion and the "extra" field will always be empty, you could go for sth. like this:

```
import json

# your mongo stuff goes here

file_content = []
with open("ttt.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        # assuming tabs and not multiple space characters
        title, desc = line.strip().split("\t", maxsplit=1) 
        file_content.append({"title": title, "description": desc, "extra": None})

collection.insert(json.dumps(file_content))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!